# stat_function conflict with loop in R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, histogram

I have a table called join_boin. and there is 4 column.

```
list <- c("a", "b", "c", "d)

function <- function(a){
  
  for (i in list){
    table %>%
      ggplot(aes(!!as.name(i)))+
      geom_histogram(aes(y=amount)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(table$a), sd = sd(table$a)))  -> result
    
    print(result)
  }
}
```

When I use a loop to create a distribution for 4 variable's histograms, I don't know how to deal with (mean = mean(table $ DIFFERENT VARIABLES) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$`, use `[[`.  In the OP's code, the argument passed into function is `av_total`, whereas the `for` loop uses the `list` object created outside the function.  It should be the same as `av_total` (or change the argument to 'av_total_list')

```
functiona <- function(data, av_total_list){  
   for(av_total in av_total_list) {
    data %>%
      ggplot(aes(!!as.name(av_total)))+
      geom_histogram(aes(y= ..density..), bins = 42) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, colour = "red", 
                args = list(mean = mean(data[[av_total]]),
             sd = sd(data[[av_total]])))  -> myresult
    
    print(myresult)
  }
}
```

and call it as

```
functiona(join_boston, list)
```

reproducible with

```
vec <- c('mpg', 'disp', 'hp')
functiona(mtcars, vec)
```

---

The above function just `print` the output into the console.  Instead, it may be better to create a function that `return` the output and loop over the `list` and apply the function

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
functionb <- function(data, av_total) {
      data %>%
        ggplot(aes(.data[[av_total]])) + 
            geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 42) + 
            stat_function(fun = dnorm, colour = "red",
              args = list(mean = mean(data[[av_total]], na.rm = TRUE),
                        sd = sd(data[[av_total]], na.rm = TRUE)))
       }
```

and call the function by loop over the column names

```
out <- map(list, ~ functionb(join_boston, .x))
```

As a reproducible example for testing

```
data(mtcars)
library(ggpubr)
vec <- c('mpg', 'disp', 'hp')
out <- map(vec, ~ functionb(mtcars, .x))
ggarrange(plotlist = out, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: hi, it gives me an error as:Error in tbl_subset2(x, j = i, j_arg = substitute(i)) : object 'av_total' not found.. So, maybe my question is how I change join_boston$DIFFERENT varible name in my list THANK you!!!

Comment: @island1996 how di you call it? Did you call the function as `functiona(list)`

Comment: I also tried use args = list(mean = mean(join_boston$list), sd = sd(join_boston$list)) while it could run but give me no disturbution line

Comment: I called it as functiona <- function(av_total)

Comment: @island1996 can you try the second function.  It is working with mtcars